# upload with jquery form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using jquery.Form to upload with jquery.
I wish to click the link Upload 1, Upload 2, Upload 3, Upload 4, opens the window for selecting files and does the upload. This code below works only if I press the Upload link only once. If I press once Uploading 1 (works) and Upload 2 (does not work), Upload 3 (not working), Upload 4 (does not work).

Why?

```
<a href="#" class="open">Upload 1</a>
<a href="#" class="open">Upload 2</a>
<a href="#" class="open">Upload 3</a>
<a href="#" class="open">Upload 4</a>

<form id="myForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="photo" class="input"  style="display: block; visibility: hidden;"/>
 </form>

<div id="message"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.open').click(function(){
    $('.input').click();
    $('.input').change(function() {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    });  
});

var options = { 
  complete: function(response) 
  {
    $("#message").html("<font color='green'>"+response.responseText+"</font>");
  },
  error: function()
  {
    $("#message").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");
  }    
}; 

   $("#myForm").ajaxForm(options);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Try to give id's for each individual input and try to see if it uploads

Comment: it's working fine for me here http://jsfiddle.net/gPvGr/

Comment: ya for me too, its working

Comment: I put on-line the script so you can try. http://alessandrocosta.biz/test/
If you try to click Upload 1 (works), immediately after if you try to click Upload 2 (start at 2 requests).

Why?